# R shiny: use css template to action button

Tags: jquery, html, css, r, shiny

I want to change layout of actionButton in shiny with css file. I define action button in server.R and use as uiOutput() in ui.R as below

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$ActionButtonExample <- renderUI({
      actionButton(
      inputId = "ActionButtonExample",
      label = "Accept",
      icon = icon("check"),
      width = '50%',
      style = 'float:right;'
    )
  })

})
```

ui.R

```
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       sliderInput("bins",
                   "Number of bins:",
                   min = 1,
                   max = 50,
                   value = 30)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       uiOutput("ActionButtonExample")
    )
  )
))
```

Could somebody explain how to style button for example with css define here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/l05nD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example for the button. The checkboxInput will be similar. Note that since the input elements are rendered by the server end using `uiOutput` and `renderUI`, they are in fact created by JavaScript in user's browser after the HTML document is loaded. Thus `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()` both do not work. The example below uses the following steps:

1. After the window load event, use `setInterval` to continuously poll the page every 0.1 seconds to see if the button is rendered.
2. After the button appears, remove the polling
3. Find the button by id, and remove the default `btn-default` class (otherwise the button text will be black and not readable)
4. Add the required 3D classes.

Code

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  includeCSS("www/btn3d.css"),

  titlePanel("Example"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("button"),
      tags$head(tags$script(HTML("
         $(window).load(function() {
            var i = setInterval(function() {
              if ($('#buttonid').length) {
                clearInterval(i);
                $('#buttonid').removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn3d btn-primary');
              }
            }, 100);
         });
      ")))
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$button <- renderUI({
    actionButton("buttonid", "buttonname")  
  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: what about checkboxinput, when they do jot have class argument? example: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/jquery-checkbox-buttons

Comment: If there is no class argument, you'll need to use jQuery to find the element using id or class, and add the needed classes using jQuery's `addClass` function on the event of document ready. Alternatively, you can modify your CSS file to point to the specific id/class

Comment: could you give an example in your answer for checkboxInput defined in server.R and called from ui.R as uiOutput?

Comment: Actually the checkbox example in your link is quite different, as it's implemented in jQuery, not pure CSS like the one in your original question. You might want to ask that in a new question.

Comment: ok, similar to this question is using this example http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/n2NB8. Since that is my first try to use css in shiny app i would be grateful for example with exact code ui.R and server.R in this case to see the logic of using checkboxInput with css file

Comment: As I checked your solution with actionButton in Internet Explorer, it does not work.

Comment: I'll try to create an example, but there is no guarantee that it will work with IE, as IE does not support many newer JS/CSS techniques.

Comment: Check in Google Chrome and it does not work,too. Please post detailed example.

Comment: Thank you! Could you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925148/r-shiny-use-css-for-checkboxinput and give as clear explanation as you used here?