# R shiny: use css for checkboxInput

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I post a simple example of checkboxInput in shiny (sample of my full code, there is a reason why I use uiOutput in ui.R). However I would like to use css layout for checkbox posted here http://codepen.io/geedmo/pen/kBHsI/. That will be my first try with using css in shiny app, so I would be grateful for implementation in shiny code posted example.

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  uiOutput("checkbox")

))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$checkbox <- renderUI({

   checkboxInput('checkboxid',
                 'Check me',
                 FALSE)

  })

})
```

Comment: Here is how to add your custom CSS to your shiny app: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html Maybe you will need to write your own `checkboxInput` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to see a more elegant solution than the one I have come up to. The code below is practically a reconstruction of http://codepen.io/geedmo/pen/kBHsI/ from the question. Copy the complied css into style.css and put it in the www folder. The compiled HTML is modified to include the attributes and tags required by shiny to work.

This is the code:

```
    library(shiny)

    ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
            HTML("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'>"),

       titlePanel("Checkboxgroup"),
       fluidRow(
       HTML(
               '<div id="checkGroup" class="form-group shiny-input-checkboxgroup shiny-input-container-inline">
                            <!--div class="shiny-options-group" -->
                                    <div class="btn-switch btn-switch-primary form-group">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="input-btn-switch-primary" name="checkGroup" value="1"/>
                                            <label for="input-btn-switch-primary" class="btn btn-round btn-primary"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></em><strong> CLICK ME</strong></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-switch btn-switch-success  form-group">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="input-btn-switch-success" name="checkGroup" value="2"/>
                                            <label for="input-btn-switch-success" class="btn btn-round btn-success"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></em><strong> CLICK ME</strong></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-switch btn-switch-info  form-group">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="input-btn-switch-info" name="checkGroup" value="3"/>
                                            <label for="input-btn-switch-info" class="btn btn-round btn-info"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></em><strong> CLICK ME</strong></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-switch btn-switch-warning  form-group">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="input-btn-switch-warning" name="checkGroup" value="4"/>
                                            <label for="input-btn-switch-warning" class="btn btn-round btn-warning"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></em><strong> CLICK ME</strong></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="btn-switch btn-switch-danger  form-group">
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="input-btn-switch-danger" name="checkGroup" value="5"/>
                                            <label for="input-btn-switch-danger" class="btn btn-round btn-danger"><em class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></em><strong> CLICK ME</strong></label>
                                    </div>
                            <!-- /div -->
               </div>'
       ),
       textOutput("selectedOptions")
    )

    ))


    server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

       output$selectedOptions <- renderText({
          paste("Selected options:", paste((input$checkGroup), collapse = " "), sep = " ")
       })
    })


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: your solution does not work well, checkbox is with standard shiny icon and next to this icon is button checkbox.

Comment: Have you also created the style.css and put it in www folder? I have deployed it on [shinyapps](https://altervalter.shinyapps.io/q054/) where you can see how it is displayed.